# Equivalent of com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.populate() for OpenStreeMaps (OSMDroid)

Tags: android, google-maps, populate, openstreetmap, android-maps

Any idea what's the equivalent of `com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.populate()` method in case of `OpenSteeMapViewItemizedOverlay` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be one. The data you pass into the constructor is already a list of OverlayItem objects. In the standard ItemizedOverlay, you must call populate(), so that the overlay iterates over the list of data and calls createItem() to create OverlayItems for each piece of data but in OpenstreetMapViewItemizedOverlay you have already create the OverlayItems so you don't need that step. The drawback I see though is that you cannot change the overlay once you create it though.